# Windows 8 Explorer UNC path

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, unc

We have 3 Windows 8.1 PCs setup. On one of the PCs we have shared a directory.
On the other 2 machines, we define a drive letter to access

```
net use h: \\computer1\hfolder (user and pwd) /persistent:yes
```

On all 3 machines, we can access H: via the command shell without a problem.

On **only 1** of 2 client machines, we can use the `h:` in Explorer directly and browse the files

On **only 1** of the 2 client machines, we can use the UNC path in Explorer directly (e.g. `\\computer1\hfolder`) and browse the files

In code on the bad PC, we cannot use the UNC path, but can use `H:` to access files.

Any idea what setting is messed up on the 3rd 'special' client PC?

Comment: Is UAC enabled? Do you map these drives with an elevated command prompt?

Comment: We mapped the drives w/ 'net use' elevated and have the same UAC settings on the machines

Answer (score 1):

Elevated processes essentially run in a separate session. Non-elevated programs do not have access to their resources. This also means that when you map a connection in an elevated command prompt, it won’t be available to non-elevated applications at all. By default.

Whether or not mapped network drives (or even sessions, especially noticable with password prompts) are shared between the regular and elevated session is controlled by a registry entry. To enabled shared connections, import this `.reg` code:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLinkedConnections"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Sounded plausible, but it doesn't seem to be the whole solution for this PC. Thanks!